# Unable to connect to Google Cloud VM instance after instance storage got full

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have been working on a VM instance. I ran a code that resulted in the complete utilization of the VM instance's storage. The code executed halfway and got killed, so I stopped the instance. Now that I restarted the instance and tried to access the VM, it keeps on showing the message "Connecting... transferring SSH keys to VM" but does not proceed to display the SSH terminal screen.

Other instances are working fine just this instance is not, probably because of the storage. Any solutions or approaches are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

One option to get out of this situation is:

Unmount the persistent disk from your GCE instance, or even better [create a snapshot from the persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) and then create a clone of the affected disk.

[Mount this disk as a "secondary" disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk) to an other running instance (best with the same OS as on the affected disk)

You can then remove some unneeded files, or even increase the disk size, to get some free space on the disk.
After that, you can umount it again from the instance, and rebuild your affected instance, by using this repaired disk as boot device.

See also the following support article on the Google Cloud Platform documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#use_your_disk_on_a_new_instance
There the process for how to unmount a problematic disk from an existing GCE instance, and how to debug it in a "debug-instance" is described along with all the required gcloud commands is described.

Comment: I am facing a few issues while doing this, once it is done I will vote on your answer!

Comment: @AbhiramSatputé 
I hope it works for you.
I deeply recommend taking a snapshot as a first step, so you don't loose any data, no matter what you do with the disk.

Comment: I have tried multiple approaches, and I did take the snapshot. I still has some problem, when I try to connect to VM using gcloud via gcloud compute ssh "instance-name" it says permission denied (public key). Didn't work with sudo either

Comment: @AbhiramSatputé
Yes, the snapshot doesn't repair anything. It is just a fallback option, to create new disks, if you destroy anything while trying to repair it.

You have to set up a new instance with a fresh and running image, and attach the  disk that is completely full to that instance.
Then you should be able to access the disk from this "debugging instance" and delete some files, disable your code that filled that disk completely, etc.